# windows server 2012 r2 server, RDP issue

Tags: windows-server-2012

i am unable to connect my DC/ADC server RDP by using administrator account,i am getting error:other user remote login requires that you have permission to log in using remote desktop server. the members of the group. administrators are equipped with this right by default. if the group you belong to does not have this privilege or the group administrators has been revoked. it must be assigned to you manually.

some of the GPO settings are changed, some one help me to resolve the same.

i did below steps to solve the issue, but no use

1. local policy -> user right assignment -> allow log on through remote desktop services -> added administrator account
2. rdp settings -> added administrator account in advanced settings

Comment: From **System** > **Advanced system settings** > **Remote** *tab* in the **Remote Desktop** section, ensure the **Allow remote connections to this complete** is *checked*, and then from **Select Users...** add this account in there assuming it's not in the **Domain Admins** domain security group since this is a "domain controller", this may be what's going on here: https://i.imgur.com/5moVOXe.png. . . Just hit the Win Flag key, type in System and click on it once it populates, and then select the **Advanced system settings** option from there and follow the above instructions. Easy to try!!

Comment: Did you add the Administrator account or the Domain Administrator account to the local security policy (there's a difference)? It would be better to add the `Domain Admins` group to that policy. Also, are there any domain group policies that are overriding this local policy setting? Is anything set in the *Deny* version of the policy?

Comment: Is this your domain administrator account as in the actual admin or an AD account with other level of admin access?